# Can you manually set resolution (pixel height/width) for Firefox 3 on Linux?

Tags: linux, firefox, flash, fedora

Trying to get my 800px width swf to take up the full width of the browser, but Firefox always shrinks it to about 2/3 size.  Wondering if I can manually set the width FF opens up to, so that my swf will display at full resolution.  Running Fedora 10.  Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can force the brownser open at a certain size. Unfortunally I cannot tell you how to do so, I don't know Javascript, but seeing that noone replied yet, I am just pointing a possible direction of research.